# Add hover to ly_text in rbokeh

Tags: r, bokeh, rbokeh

Is it possible to add hover text to an `ly_text()` layer in rbokeh? For example, how can I add hover text to the numbers drawn in this figure?

```
d = data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5, text=as.character(1:5))
figure() %>% ly_text(x, y, text, data=d)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if `ly_text` had a `hover` argument that would make it easy :-) In my real application the text is longer and closer together than in the example so I would like the hover region to correspond to the actual extent of the text. Is there a way to use `hover_tool` to do this? Or a way to measure the text and draw an invisible rectangle with the hover?